# How to create and develope android application with my team?

Tags: android

i have a programmer team for android. now i have create and develop android application with my team.
how can i do it?

is possible this work?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Comment: What type of app do you need? I feel this question is opinion based until it is a problem in a particular portion while developing your concept/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `SVN` or `GIT`, they are softwares for `versioning`, all of you could work on the same file and in the end all of you `commit` that file, and `update` it again so everyone have the most recent copy.

hope this helps